# Extract Datatype from Cell Values in PowerQuery?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

[image: My Tables]

How can I save the datatype of each cell into a new column? I want the 'Custom' column to display the datatypes of each item in the "values" column. I've tried using `Value.Type([values])` but the output just displays this 'Type' value. If I click on 'Type' it creates a new navigation query and I can see that the datatypes are saved inside of it but I can't seem to extract them.

[image: Inside 'Types']

Comment: Interesting question. [This](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/How-to-print-out-quot-type-text-quot-or-quot-type-number-quot-as/td-p/1051578) is a possible solution but I don't like it.

Comment: Thanks! That solution works. I am now facing a new issue when trying to use this method after splitting columns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70342312/split-column-without-converting-to-text-in-power-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Primitive vs Ascribed types

@AlexisOlson:

> [This](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/How-to-print-out-quot-type-text-quot-or-quot-type-number-quot-as/td-p/1051578) is a possible solution but I don't like it.

You're right, that answer is not correct. It uses `Table.Schema`, [which tests  for ascribed types That's usually the right type, but if data isn't transformed correctly, it can be wrong](https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2020/09/03/5408/power-query-m-primer-part19-type-system-iv-ascription-conformance-and-equalitys-strange-behaviors)

You need to use `Value.Type()` to get the real /  actual [primitive type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-types#primitive-types)

### Query

[image: table showing typenames as text]

```
let
    Sample = {
        123, 0.45, true,
        "text",
        Currency.From(12.34),
        Int64.From(91),
        DateTime.LocalNow(), DateTimeZone.FixedLocalNow(), #date(2021,1,3),
        #duration(0,0,1,3), #binary({2,3,4}),
        #table(type table[Foo=text], {{"bar"}}),
        [ a = "b" ],
        each "x",
        {0..3}
    },
    records = List.Transform(
        Sample,
        (item) => [
            Original = item, 
            Name = TypeToText( Value.Type( item )) 
        ]
    ),
    Final = Table.FromRecords( records, type table[Original = any, Name = text])
in
    Final
```

### Type.ToText.pq

This is the simplified version of `_serialize_typename()` which contains true serialization at [DataConnectors/UnitTesting.query.pq](https://github.com/microsoft/DataConnectors/blob/460babf2f8c44ec82d7e08d1b65b156984c6ba75/samples/UnitTesting/UnitTesting.query.pq#L210-L244)

```
let
    Type.ToText =  (x, optional funtype as logical) =>
        let
            isFunctionType = (x as type) => try if Type.FunctionReturn(x) is type then true else false otherwise false,
            isTableType = (x as type) =>  try if Type.TableSchema(x) is table then true else false otherwise false,
            isRecordType = (x as type) => try if Type.ClosedRecord(x) is type then true else false otherwise false,
            isListType = (x as type) => try if Type.ListItem(x) is type then true else false otherwise false
        in
            if funtype = null and isTableType(x) then "Table"
            else if funtype = null and isListType(x) then "list"
            else if funtype = null and isFunctionType(x) then "Function"
            else if funtype = null and isRecordType(x) then "Record"
            else if x = type any then "any"
            else let base = Type.NonNullable(x) in
                (if Type.IsNullable(x) then "nullable " else "") &
                (if base = type anynonnull then "anynonnull" else
                if base = type binary then "binary" else
                if base = type date   then "date"   else
                if base = type datetime then "datetime" else
                if base = type datetimezone then "datetimezone" else
                if base = type duration then "duration" else
                if base = type logical then "logical" else
                if base = type none then "none" else
                if base = type null then "null" else
                if base = type number then "number" else
                if base = type text then "text" else
                if base = type time then "time" else
                if base = type type then "type" else

                /* Abstract types: */
                if base = type function then "function" else
                if base = type table then "table" else
                if base = type record then "record" else
                if base = type list then "list"
                else "any /*Actually unknown type*/")
in
    Type.ToText
```